# Solving $4\lfloor x \rfloor=x+\{x\}$. What is wrong in my solution? Can anyone tell?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

$\lfloor x \rfloor$ = Floor Function, and $\{x\}$ denotes fractional part function

> Solve for $x$
> $$4\lfloor x \rfloor= x + \{x\}$$

$ x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\}$

$\implies x - \{x\} = \lfloor x \rfloor$

$\implies 4x - 4\{x\} = x + \{x\}$

$\implies 3x = 5\{x\}$

Note that ,

$\implies 0 \leq  \{x\}<1$

$\implies 0 \leq 5\{x\} < 5 \iff 0 \leq 3x <5 \iff\boxed{ 0 \leq x < \dfrac{5}{3}}$

But the answer is $ x = 0$

Comment: You proved that the solution is in the interval $\left[0, \frac{5}{3}\right]$ but not all the the elements of the interval are solutions.

Comment: It will be better to replace $x$ in the equation by $\lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\}$ and use the fact that $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is integer.

Comment: You should try to write more text explaining how your steps relate. You have edited out the confusing $\Longrightarrow$ but ideally, you would start your argument with something like “From the definition of floor and the fractional part, we have …” instead of just dropping a formula. Text like this will often make your arguments *much* easier to read. (Also note that there is still a superfluous $\Longrightarrow$ after “Note that”.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly deduced that $\color{blue}{0\leq x<\frac 53}$. To get the solution, the given equation $4\lfloor x\rfloor=x+\{x\}$ must also be satisfied.

Note that $x=1$ does not satisfy the given equation. If $x>1$, then $\lfloor x\rfloor=1$ and hence $4=x+\{x\}<\frac 53+1=8/3$ (by the blue colored inequality) , which is not possible.

Hence it follows that $0\leq x<1$.

Since, $\lfloor x\rfloor=0$, it follows that $\color{red}{x+\{x\}=0}$ (due to the given equation).

The identity $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$ gives $x=\{x\}$, which along-with the red-colored equation gives: $x=0$.

Comment: I am new to solving floor function, so i wanted to ask do we have to always keep checking the result we get? 
For eg like you checked if $0 \leq x < \dfrac{5}{3}$ satisfies the equation by putting $x=1$

Comment: @Aqua: The point of solving an equation for an unknown is to arrive at something for the desired unknown that satisfies the original (given) equation so it's always a good practice to do the checking.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned elsewhere, your conclusion is correct, but inconclusive. It might be easier to see what is going on if we write everything in terms of $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\{x\}$:

$$
\begin{align}
4\lfloor x\rfloor
&= x+\{x\}\tag{1a}\\
&=\lfloor x\rfloor+2\{x\}\tag{1b}\\
\lfloor x\rfloor
&=\tfrac23\{x\}\tag{1c}\\
0&\le\lfloor x\rfloor\lt\tfrac23\tag{1d}\\
\lfloor x\rfloor&=0\tag{1e}\\
\{x\}&=0\tag{1f}\\
x&=0\tag{1g}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: copied equation
$\text{(1b)}$: $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$
$\text{(1c)}$: solve $\text{(1a)}$ and $\text{(1b)}$ for $\lfloor x\rfloor$
$\text{(1d)}$: $\text{(1c)}$ and $0\le\{x\}\lt1$
$\text{(1e)}$: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is an integer
$\text{(1f)}$: combine $\text{(1c)}$ and $\text{(1e)}$
$\text{(1g)}$: $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$

Answer (score 1):

How did you get from $$4\lfloor x \rfloor = x + \{x\}$$
to
$$x=\lfloor x\rfloor + \{x\}?$$

The two equations are not equivalent!

---

But OK, ignoring the very awkward way the solution is written, there is nothing really *wrong* with your solution, in the sense that you correctly prove that **if** $4\lfloor x \rfloor = x + \{x\}$, **then** $0\leq x<\frac53$. However, your mistake is then saying that every $x$ satisfying the equation $0\leq x < \frac53$  is also a solution to the original equation, and that is simply not true. For example, $x=\frac12$ does not satisfy the equation.

Comment: You interpreted it wrong i guess. The Question is 

Solve for $x$ 

$4\lfloor x \rfloor = x + \{x\}$

Comment: I thought that, too, at first, but $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \{ x \}$ follows from the definition of floor and fractional part.

Comment: @Aqua Well you wrote $4\lfloor x \rfloor = x + \{x\}\implies x=\lfloor x\rfloor + \{x\}$, so how else do you expect me to interpret it?

Comment: That said, using $\Rightarrow$ next to it is certainly confusing.

Comment: Oh i am really sorry about that implies sign , i have edited the question

Comment: @Aqua I expanded my answer with an explanation of the main issue of your argument.

Answer (score 1):

$0 \leq x <\frac 53 $ is correct. This implies that $[x]=0$ or $[x]+1$. In the first case  we get $x+\{x\}=0$ which implies $x=0$. Suppose $[x]=1$. Then we have $1 \leq x <\frac 53 $ from which  we get $4<\frac 5 3 +1$ which is wrong. Hence we must have $x=0$.

Answer (score -1):

We have :
$$4 \lfloor x \rfloor = x + \{x\} = \lfloor x \rfloor + 2 \{x\}$$
then :
$$2 \{x\} = 3 \lfloor x \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}$$
We deduce that :
$$\{x\} = 0 \text{ or } \{x\} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

1. If $\{x\} = 0$ then $3 \lfloor x \rfloor = 2 \{x\} = 0$. It means that $\lfloor x \rfloor = 0$ then $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\} = 0$.
2. If $\{x\} = \dfrac{1}{2}$ then $3 \lfloor x \rfloor = 2 \{x\} = 1$.  It means that $\lfloor x \rfloor = \dfrac{1}{3}$ wich is impossible because $\lfloor x \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The unique solution is $x = 0$.